# Powershell Forms: How to validate different types of System.Windows.Forms together?

Tags: forms, powershell, combobox, scripting

I have created a PowerShell form containing both TextBox and ComboBox fields that are listed in the form in the following order:

1. TextBox
2. ComboBox
3. ComboBox
4. ComboBox
5. TextBox

I then have an OK Button at the bottom of the form which is set to disabled to begin with.

I want to be able to validate that all 5 fields contains some text before the OK button becomes enabled, but have hit a snag in that it doesn't seem that the 
two types of boxes interact together that I can see.
Below is what I have so far - this gives me either:

1. If both TextBoxes contain text, OK button is enabled
2. Or...if the three ComboBoxes contain text, the OK button is enabled

```
$objSvrBox.Add_TextChanged({If($This.Text -and $objEmailBox.Text){$OKButton.Enabled = $True}Else{$OKButton.Enabled = $False}})
$objDomDropDown.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({If($This.Text -and $objOSDropDown.Text -and $objMDCDropDown.Text){$OKButton.Enabled = $True}Else{$OKButton.Enabled = $False}})
$objOSDropDown.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({If($This.Text -and $objDomDropDown.Text -and $objMDCDropDown.Text){$OKButton.Enabled = $True}Else{$OKButton.Enabled = $False}})
$objMDCDropDown.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({If($This.Text -and $objDomDropDown.Text -and $objOSDropDown.Text){$OKButton.Enabled = $True}Else{$OKButton.Enabled = $False}})
$objEmailBox.Add_TextChanged({If($This.Text -and $objSvrBox.Text){$OKButton.Enabled = $True}Else{$OKButton.Enabled = $False}})
```

... but I cant seem to be able to combine the code together to keep all 5 fields happy and working together - hence the first and last lines are still separate. Is there a way to combine this code together or possibly a simpler method I've overlooked?
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

First I would create a function to handle the validation, and attach that function to an event on each of the desired form controls.
Create the function:

```
function validateBoxesAndCombos(){
     if($objSvrBox.Text -and $objEmailBox.Text -and $objDomDropDown.Text -and $objOSDropDown.Text -and $objMDCDropDown.Text){
           $OKButton.Enabled = $true
     }
     else{
           $OKButton.Enabled = $false
    }
}
```

Then attach this function to an event on the boxes and combos.

```
$objSvrBox.Add_TextChanged({validateBoxesAndCombos})
$objEmailBox.Add_TextChanged({validateBoxesAndCombos})
$objDomDropDown.Add_TextChanged({validateBoxesAndCombos})
$objOSDropDown.Add_TextChanged({validateBoxesAndCombos})
$objMDCDropDown.Add_TextChanged({validateBoxesAndCombos})
```

I avoided using the selectedIndexChanged event for the combos because that will not fire when someone enters a value into the combo box, nor will it fire if, after selecting an item, the user deletes the text.

That is all there is to it. This code will enable the OK button only if all 5 fields contain text. If any field is blanked out by the user then the OK button will be disabled.

Please note that in this solution the textboxes and comboboxes must be declared in a way that they are accessible to the function.

In the event that the user is not allowed to enter values into the drop downs and is forced to select existing values you can do either of the following:

1) Continue using the TextChanged event for the combos, but add a blank item to the collection. Selecting the blank item, with the condition as defined in the function, will disable the OK button.

2) Go back to using the SelectedIndexChanged Event. You will still attach the validateBoxesAndCombos function, but for the combo boxes it will be done like this:

```
$objDomDropDown.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({validateBoxesAndCombos})
```

Then you will want to change your condition in the function in one of two ways:

a) check the selected index like this

```
$objDropDown.SelectedIndex -ne -1
```

where -1 means that nothing is selected. Or

b) make the first item of each drop down something like "Please Select an Option" and then check the selectedIndex like this:

```
$objDropDown.SelectedIndex -gt 0
```

where 0 means that the default message is selected, and anything greater than 0 means a selection was made.

Comment: please note you can keep the conditions within the event code blocks but putting them in a function is simply cleaner and easier to maintain.