# How skip empty values in new-aduser

Tags: powershell

Hello I write program that will be create user from powershell gui, and i have problem:
Sometimes not all field have values and they empty, but when i try create user with parameter that have empty value i get error

```
new-aduser server is unwilling to process the request
```

I can use many if-else blocks foreach field but i think it's not good solution.Please help have can i pass create user with empty parameters.

```
New-ADUser     -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String ($Password.Text)) `
               -GivenName $UserName.Text `
               -Company $company.Text `
               -EmployeeID $Tabel.Text `
               -HomePhone $homephone.Text `
               -MobilePhone $mobilephone.Text `
               -Enabled $true `
               -SamAccountName $Login.Text `
               -StreetAddress $street.Text `
               -Surname $Surname.Text `
               -Title $JobPost.Text `
               -UserPrincipalName ($Login.Text + "@domain.com") `
               -OfficePhone $phone.Text `
               -Office $office.Text `
               -Description $SZnumb.Text `
               -City $City.Text `
               -Department $Departament.Text `
               -Division $Division.Text `
               -Name ($Surname.Text + " " + $UserName.Text + " " + $FatherName.Text) `
               -DisplayName ($Surname.Text + " " + $UserName.Text + " " + $FatherName.Text) `
               -Path $OUpicker.Text `
               -PasswordNeverExpires $passneverexpires `
               -ChangePasswordAtLogon $changepassatlogon `
               -CannotChangePassword $cantchangepassword `
               -OtherAttributes @{ 'employeeType' = $LevelRuler.Text; 'extensionAttribute4'=$Sektor.Text}
```

**Update**

Problem with parameter `-OtherAttributes` if that two field empty it's throw error

Comment: Have you considered [input validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32744858/503046)? Disable the OK button and enable it only after all the required fields are filled.

Comment: Some account types do not have required that field data.

Comment: You have to define acceptable use cases. Maybe a dropdown or radio button would pick account type, and based on account type, select appropriate input validation options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion by [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) sounds like a good one. 
You can have something like a radio button defining what account type you are dealing with and based on that disable or hide some of the input boxes.

Anyway, I think you should really consider switching to using Splatting. This makes better readable and maintanable code (no more nasty backticks) **AND** you can add or leave out properties depending on certain conditions.

Something like:

```
# build a Hashtable object for splatting, at first with properties all account types have in common
# for instance:
$userParams = @{
    AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String ($Password.Text))
    GivenName             = $UserName.Text
    Company               = $company.Text
    EmployeeID            = $Tabel.Text
    HomePhone             = $homephone.Text
    MobilePhone           = $mobilephone.Text
    Enabled               = $true
    SamAccountName        = $Login.Text
    StreetAddress         = $street.Text
    Surname               = $Surname.Text
    Title                 = $JobPost.Text
    UserPrincipalName     = ($Login.Text + "@atbmarket.com")
    Description           = $SZnumb.Text
    City                  = $City.Text
    Department            = $Departament.Text
    Division              = $Division.Text
    Name                  = ($Surname.Text + " " + $UserName.Text + " " + $FatherName.Text)
    DisplayName           = ($Surname.Text + " " + $UserName.Text + " " + $FatherName.Text)
    Path                  = $OUpicker.Text
    PasswordNeverExpires  = $passneverexpires
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $changepassatlogon
    CannotChangePassword  = $cantchangepassword
}
```

Now, you can add certain extra properties, depending on the account type. For instance:

```
switch ($LevelRuler.Text) {
    'Manager' { 
        $userParams['OtherAttributes'] = @{'employeeType' = 'Manager'; 'extensionAttribute4'=$Sektor.Text}
    }
    'FloorWalker' {
        $userParams['OtherAttributes'] = @{'employeeType' = 'FloorWalker' }
    }
    # etc.
}
```

And add other common properties only if they are not blank:

```
if (!([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($phone.Text))) {
    $userParams['OfficePhone'] = $phone.Text.Trim()
}
if (!([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($office.Text))) {
    $userParams['Office'] = $office.Text.Trim()
}
# etc.
```

Finally, create the new user:

```
New-ADUser @userParams
```

<sup>P.S.1 is this a typo? `$Departament.Text`</sup>

<sup>P.S.2 Instead of doing `($Surname.Text + " " + $UserName.Text + " " + $FatherName.Text)` twice, I'd create a variable $name first like `$name = ('{0} {1} {2}' -f $Surname.Text, $UserName.Text, $FatherName.Text).Trim() -replace '\s+', ' '` and use that for properties Name and DisplayName</sup>