# I am getting a "New-ADUser : The object name has bad syntax" error when i try to create users from a CSV file

Tags: powershell

I am getting a "New-ADUser : The object name has bad syntax" error when I try to create users from a CSV file.  I can't seem to figure out why. I have additional columns with empty fields on the CSV file I don't use to create the users. I use those columns later to populate attributes in AD later.

```
$ADUsers = Import-csv "C:\sdk\students to create2.csv"

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
        
    $usual_Name         = $user.usual_Name
    $Given_Name         = $User.Given_Name
    $Surname            = $User.Surname
    $UPN                = $User.UPN
    $Username           = $User.username
    $Password           = $User.password
    $OU         = $User.ou #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be created in
    $Password = $User.Password


    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
    {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else
    {
        #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account
        
        #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$UPN" `
            -Name $Username `
            -GivenName $Usual_Name `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$Usual_Name $Surname" `
            -Path $OU `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False

    
            
            #-AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is obviously with the data in the CSV, please post a sample of the CSV that reproduces the error

Comment: $lastname is not set.  Try strict mode.

Comment: Also `-ChangePasswordAtLogon $False` needs to be on its own line.Please read about [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), so you can get rid of syntax using the horrible backticks. Search on SO to find many, MANY examples of how to create ad users using data from a csv while avoiding empty properties, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62064400/9898643) for instance

Comment: This issue is resolved, the problem was with the csv file, i must have stared at it for over an hour with the problem staring back at me right in the face. Thanks to Mathias I found the issue after looking at it for the tenth time.